# Custom Preview Template for Dropzone JS

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms, dropzone.js

I created a form with the dropzone, but I'm having issues passing the files to the server. I created a custom preview template, similar to the one on the bootstrap demo, but when I click on submit on my form, the files are not being passed to the server. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the code.

```
 <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="dropzoner dropzone-previews" id="dropzoner2">
          <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview" id="template">  <!-- template for images -->
            <div class="dz-details dztemplate">
              <div class="dz-filename" style="display:none;"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
              <div class="dz-size"  style="display:none;" data-dz-size></div>
              <img data-dz-thumbnail /><br/><input type="text" class="dzinput" placeholder="Type Caption" style="font-style:italic;" />
            </div>
            <div class="dz-progress" style="display:none;"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
            <div class="dz-success-mark" style="display:none;"><span>✔</span></div>
            <div class="dz-error-mark" style="display:none;"><span>✘</span></div>
            <div class="dz-error-message" style="display:none;"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- Drop Zone Area -->
        <div class="flrt"><a href="#" class="dz-message" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:18px;">Or use the basic uploader</a></div><br/>
      <label for="exampletitle">Title<span class="required">*</span></label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="exampletitle" id="exampletitle" class="fullwidth" required>      <br/><br/>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mypanoramabtn" style="background-color:#3ebede" value="Publish" id="submitter"/>
 </form>
```

My Javascript:

```
//getting thumbnail template
  var previewNode = document.querySelector("#template");
  previewNode.id = "";
  var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
  previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);

 //script to handle dropzone
  jQuery("#my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element

  // The configuration we've talked about above
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  uploadMultiple: true,
  thumbnailWidth: 180,
  thumbnailHeight: 120,
  parallelUploads: 100,
  maxFiles: 100,
  previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
  previewsContainer: "#dropzoner2",

  // The setting up of the dropzone
  init: function() {
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) { document.getElementById("dropzoner2").style.background = "none";});  //will remove background after file added
    var myDropzone = this;

    // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
    this.element.querySelector("input[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      myDropzone.processQueue();
    });

    // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
    // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
    this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
      // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
      // Hide the success button or the complete form.

    });
    this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
      // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
      // Redirect user or notify of success.
    });
    this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
      // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
      // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
    });
  }

}
```

I've tried the demos on the wiki and a few others on stackoverflow, but have been unable to get this to work. Right now when I drag and drop my images, I do see the thumbnail in my template, but when I click submit, the images are not passed to the server for me to handle. ANY help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should provide some more info about that is not working. Post up what the network request to the server looks like. You can open up debugger tools and go to the networking tab and watch it as you drag and drop.